# Pulling latest JSF Mojarra implementation from Maven Repository

Tags: jsf, download, mojarra

How can I get the latest JSF 2.2 jar file from Maven repository?

In this [download](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/download.html) page there is this repository [link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/) but there are many files with different dates. I can't even find the version Mojarra 2.2.13 which is [announced](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/) as released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File names are ordered lexicographically (i.e. as strings, not as numbers). The [`2.2.13`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.13/) appears right before [`2.2.2`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.2/).

If you still can't find it, just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on "2.2.13", or click [this link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.13/javax.faces-2.2.13.jar) for the direct JAR.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice how they were ordered. Sorry to bother you with this stupid question. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I once also trapped in this during a monday morning while low on coffee, so I find this question reasonable ;)